# Is there any possible way to take a DNA test without using blood in humans?

Tags: cell-biology, dna, dna-isolation, tissue

Is there any possible way to take a DNA test without the need to draw blood in humans? Any information will be useful for me.

Comment: Hair follicle, Oral mucosa, Semen...? On theory, every cell contain chromosomes could do the DNA test, but it should depend on when and where you wanna to do the test. Some agencies don't have the ability to do small amount od DNA test, and also preservation of DNA sample is another point.

Comment: I think a more interesting question would be 'from what cell type can't we extract DNA for testing'

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we don't have to use blood to extract DNA for testing.
There are many resource we can use include: hair, buccal swabs and urine. And it seems hair can provide good quality of genome DNA.

Here is the paper you may interested: [A Simple Method of Genomic DNA Extraction from Human Samples for PCR-RFLP Analysis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3792701/)

Comment: Also this section of an article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_testing#Medical_procedure

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and is there possible To use finger print for DNA test?

Comment: @Rani Yes as epithelial cells are deposited upon contact with objects/surfaces but it is not trivial due to 1) the very low number of cells and 2) cross-contamination as, for standard protocol, dusting is first needed to see fingerprints (and you don't change the brush usually) and 3) the powder used to see fingerprints may interfere with the DNA extraction. See this [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21827455).

Comment: So, DNA test through our fingerprint is little bit difficult right sir?.. may i know is possible to take grouping blood via our fingerprint?. I mean, is it possible to find A+, O- ,.... something like this? Thank you...

Comment: Can anyone guide me please...

Comment: For a cheap and fast test of blood groups, you need blood. Unless your fingerprint has it's owner's blood, this gets more difficult. In principle, you could extract DNA (caligari2005 already explained that is bothersome) and then check the DNA sequence for the blood group alleles. But if you did extract the DNA from a fingerprint, you would have much better individuation chances with standard forensic tests than looking for a blood group allele.

Comment: @jkadlubowska: how would you told using blood, its a fast method for blood groups,.. If we use blood, it will take more time to find the blood group than the using fingerprint right? thanks..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_residue http://www.nejm.org/doi/pdf/10.1056/NEJM194910062411414

Comment: @jkadlubowska: actually i m not a medical student, can you please elaborate in the above link? thanks